# How to bypass contextpath for health.html page. Our requirement is to have health.html under classpath directly

Tags: java, spring-boot, pcf

We have a Spring Boot application where context path is defined and it is deployed in PCF as jar(please note it is not WAR file). But, our load balancer keeps checking for health.html. So I created a health.html under src/main/resources/static folder.

For eg : `server.servlet.context-path = /TransactionManagement`.

But this health.html is accessible via https://myapplication.abc.com/TransactionManagement/health.html instead of https://myapplication.abc.com/health.html.

How to bypass contextPath in this case?